# what benefits do tubeless tyres bring to a 29er trail mtb?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, 29er, tubeless

I have a 2014 Whyte T-129s and am considering converting the tires to tubeless. They are already 'tubeless compatible', so this should not be prohibitively expensive, but I am wondering whether this will really result in a better performance?

Comment: So the tires are tubeless compatible.  Are the rims tubeless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the main advantages of tubeless is that you can run [lower pressures](http://www.utahmountainbiking.com/goodies/go-tubeless.htm) (which comes with better shock absorption and thus control) with less risk of flats (though you should always carry a backup tube). I'm not entirely sure on where the truth is in regards to [weight](http://www.bicycling.com/mountainbikecom/bikes-gear/pssssst), but I don't think its [important](http://www.singletracks.com/blog/mtb-gear/how-to-tubeless-mountain-biking-guide/). The disadvantages are still having to carry a backup tube and the extra complexity of installing the tire.

In any case, if you have tubeless ready rims, its relatively cheap to try running tubeless on your own, so I think giving it a shot is the best way to convince yourself that its worth it or not.

Comment: You have to carry a back up tube if using tubed tires so not an additional disadvantage. Also fitting a tubeless tire is some cases is much easier than fitting a tubed tire if using UST rims.

Comment: Right. I forgot the word "still".

Comment: I'd add something to fix sidewall damage to the list of kit to carry. Both for tubed and tubeless setups. You can buy large rubber patches made for this job (I've some from Park Tools) or improvise - some people have managed to limp home using a banknote inside the sidewall to plug a sidewall tear and stop the tube from sticking through it.

Comment: There isn't really any extra complexity in fitting the tyre. Fit it as usual and most of the time the bead will take. I tend to use a CO2 cartridge (or a petrol station compressor) to get it on if it's troublesome. Then you just add sealant.